# Error in the karate-config makes Karate hang

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

While running karate tests I noticed that any failures which happen while running karate-config.js make the run hang and never get out of karate-config. Is there a way to either fail the test or jump out of karate-config.js in case of failures?

One of the examples of such failures is :

> 21:28:44.271 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate -
> evaluation of 'karate-config.js' failed: javascript function call
> failed:  get_token.feature:26 - evaluation (js) failed:
> input('input[id=username]', loginusername), js eval failed twice:var e
> = document.querySelector("input[id=username]"); e.focus(); try { e.selectionStart = e.selectionEnd = e.value.length } catch(x) {},
> error:
> {"type":"object","subtype":"error","className":"TypeError","description":"TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'focus' of null\n    at
> :1:57","objectId":"{"injectedScriptId":2,"id":3}"}

Comment: upgrade or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue